# Table with multiple columns and long text fitting within column

Tags: tables, columns

I am trying to construct a table with three columns in which I can fit a long text within the middle column. The code works well for 2 columns but not 3. Could some please help out?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr.5\columnwidth-2\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    %% \centering % not needed
    \caption{Simulation parameters}
    \begin{tabular}{p{\mylength}|p{\mylength}}
        \hline
    \textbf{Variable} &\textbf{Defintion} &  \textbf{Source}    \\\hline \\
        \hline
ABCDEF & Long Text Long Text LongLong Text Long Text LongLong Text Long Text LongLong Text Long Text LongLong Text Long Text Long Text & Database Name  \\ \\

        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    %\label{table: simulation parameters}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have defined only two column table ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code for table has more issues:

- defined are two columns, but you use three
- instead `\\ \hline \\ \hline` should be `\\ \hline\hline`
- table is not well balanced. you should reconsider its design, for example use of `tabularx` and `l` column type in the first column, `X` for the second column and whatever for the last (it is not clear requirement for it)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    %% \centering % not needed
    \caption{Simulation parameters}
    \begin{tabular}{*{3}{p{\dimexpr0.33\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}}
        \hline
    \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Defintion} &  \textbf{Source}    \\
        \hline\hline
ABCDEF & Long Text Long Text LongLong Text Long Text Long Long Text Long Text Long Long Text Long Text Long Long Text Long Text Long Text & Database Name  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    %\label{table: simulation parameters}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

for example a table version with `tabularx` and `booktabs`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Simulation parameters}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l X l}
        \toprule
    \textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Defintion} &  \textbf{Source}    \\
        \midrule
ABCDEF & Long Text Long Text LongLong Text Long Text Long Long Text Long Text Long Long Text Long Text Long Long Text Long Text Long Text & Database Name    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    %\label{table: simulation parameters}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful suggestion. This suggestion solves the problem.